What is the difference between OBJECT of a preposition and COMPLEMENT of a preposition in English grammar
I am an English-as-a-second-language student, and I have this doubt when studying syntactic analysis.
What is the difference between complement of a preposition and object of a preposition? Or are those just 2 different names that refer to the same thing?

Looking at answers at What are the things after prepositions called, formally? and What is a prepositional complement? would lead you to assume 'they are just 2 different names that refer to the same thing'. But people in various schools (eg the CGEL camp) wouldn't accept one term or the other.

THIS SHOULD NEVER HAVE BEEN MIGRATED TO ELL. IT BELONGS ON EL&U, WHERE IT WAS ORIGINALLY ASKED.
